# Searching a range of a float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am super new to python and am learning as I go. I have run into a problem. I need to search for a float in a dataframe column and return a dataframe that is sorted by the float. If the float is not in the dataframe I want it to search for a range of -.100 below the given float and +.200 above the given float. If found I want to return a sorted dataframe.

I tried the np.arage() function but I am getting:
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (2,), (300,))

Here is what I have so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[8,.125],[2,.375],[4,.625],[2,.188],[6,.625],[4,.500],[9,.312]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Size','WT'])

print(df)

wt = float(input("Thickness to three decimals ---> "))
wtmin = wt - .100
wtmax = wt + .200
wtrange = np.arange(wtmin, wtmax, .010)

wtdf = df.loc[df['WT'] == WT]
    if wtdf.empty:
        wtdf = df.loc[df['WT'] == wtrange]
        print(wtdf)
    else:
        print(wtdf)
```

If I input a known float the code works. If not I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following statement to check the range instead of `arange`:

```
wtdf = df.loc[df['WT'] == wt]
    if wtdf.empty:
        wtdf = df.loc[wt - .1 < df['WT'] < wt + .2].sort_values('WT')
        print(wtdf)
    else:
        print(wtdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the .between() method and it seemed to function properly. code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[8,.125],[2,.375],[4,.625],[2,.188],[6,.625],[4,.500],[9,.312]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Size','WT'])

print(df)


wt = float(input("Thickness to three decimals ---> "))
wtmin = wt - .100
wtmax = wt + .200
wtrange = np.arange(wtmin, wtmax, .010)
print(wtmin)
print(wtmax)
wtdf = df.loc[df['WT'] == wt]
if wtdf.empty:
    wtdf1 = df[df["WT"].between(wtmin,wtmax)]
    print("wtdf1 df is", wtdf1)
else:
    print(wtdf)
```